# Mongoose stream return few results first time

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am working on a new real time news service, right now I have a problem that I don´t know how to solve.

First off when the user connect to the NodeJS server I create a Mongoose stream thus I can return this data easily and rapidly.

The problem I have right now is to return the first time just a few set of data, with the next code it's returning all the collection:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("New user has been connected");

    var stream = News.find().tailable().stream();

    stream.on('error', function (err) {
      console.error(err)
    });

    stream.on('data', function (doc) {
      socket.emit("newArticle", doc);
    }); 
});
```

So, the question is... how I can return the first time just the latest ten results?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried limiting the query? Like shown in the mongoose.js docs under [queries](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/query.html).

With your code it would be

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log("New user has been connected");

  var stream = News.find().tailable().limit(10).stream();

  stream.on('error', function (err) {
    console.error(err)
  });

  stream.on('data', function (doc) {
    socket.emit("newArticle", doc);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, now looking my code I decided to get the latest articles by date, I am saving the articles with a timestamp so.. when the user connect it I am limiting the query by the articles from the current time minus one hour.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I do it limiting the query from the current time minus half an hour, in this way the first time I am just getting a little set of data.