# Mongoose QueryStream new results

Tags: node.js, mongodb, streaming, mongoose

I am trying to setup [MongooseJS](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html) to push out the whole collection (or just the newest item) when new documents are inserted into the collection by another application.

I assumed [QueryStream](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#querystream-js) was the way to go.

However, when I start my simple application, it reads out the collection once, and closes it.

When I insert a new document nothing happens (assuming the connection is no longer open and looking for new results...?)

```
var Orders = db.model('orders', OrderSchema);

var stream = Orders.find().stream();

stream.on('data', function(doc){
    console.log('New item!');
    console.log(doc);
}).on('error', function (error){
    console.log(error);
}).on('close', function () {
    console.log('closed');
});
```

Immediately prints all the items that are currently in the *orders collection*, and than prints "closed". Shouldn't the "Stream" remain open printing new data when the *collection changes*?

What am I not understanding about the `MongooseJS QueryStream`?

Ps. my goal is to eventually `emit` an updated collection via `socket.io` as demonstrated here: [Mongoose stream return few results first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075462/mongoose-stream-return-few-results-first-time?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered that in order for this method to work I needed to change my collection to a `capped collection`:

```
var OrderSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({...
}, { capped: { size: 10, max: 10, autoIndexId: true }});

var Orders = db.model('orders', OrderSchema);

var stream = Orders.find().tailable().stream();

stream.on('data', function(doc){
    console.log('New item!');
    console.log(doc);
}).on('error', function (error){
    console.log(error);
}).on('close', function () {
    console.log('closed');
});
```

This works because I can now treat the `MongoDB collection` like something of a message queue, which is continuously updated.

Strangely enough when I wrap this inside of a `SocketIO` event I get multiples of the same `documents` which makes me think there is still something I'm not doing exactly right...

Answer (score 4):

You need some mark (a timestamp or just a plain number) to don't get all collection every time you start streaming. As example, if you insert a timestamp in the collection entries, you could use:

```
    var filter = { "timestamp":{"$gte":Date.now()}};
    var stream = Orders.find(filter).tailable().stream();
```

Think about the mongoDB streaming as a `tail -f` command in bash.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try to see if I get multiple results or if that helps